# How to determine whether all real parts of the eigenvalues of a complex matrix are negative?

Tags: matrices, complex-analysis, polynomials, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hurwitz-matrices

It is well-known with respect to Routh-Hurwitz Criterion that for an arbitrary matrix $A$ with real coefficients, one can derive a series of analytic expressions with these real coefficients, so as to determine whether all real parts of eigenvalues for the matrix $A$ are negative, without solving the corresponding polynomial. However, if there exist some complex coefficients in the matrix $A$, Routh-Hurwitz Criterion may be not feasible to deal with the aforesaid issue.

In my research work, I have derived a matrix as follows:
\begin{align}
    X =   \left(
        \begin{array}{ccccc}
        {0}   & 1   & 0 & \cdots  &  {0}  \\
        0  & 0 & \ddots  & \ddots   & \vdots \\
        \vdots & \vdots &  \cdots & 1 & 0 \\
         0 &   0 & \cdots & \cdots & 1  \\
        -g_0 \lambda & -g_1 \lambda &  \cdots & \cdots & -g_{m-1}  \lambda
    \end{array}
        \right) \text{.}
\end{align}

where $g_i > 0$, $i = 0, 1, …, m - 1$, $m$ is a positive integer with $m > 1$, and $\lambda$ is a complex number. I would like to derive a criterion, similar to Routh-Hurwitz Criterion, in order to determine whether all real parts of eigenvalues for the matrix $X$ are negative via the coefficients of $X$, instead of solving the corresponding polynomial. Unfortunately, I have never found an available sufficient condition yet. Here, I am looking for your help sincerely, and thanks for your kind attention.